# Jacoco branch missed in using viewModelScope.launch

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, jacoco

I am using Jacoco in my project for calculating branch coverage, but it said that 1 of 2 branch is missing in the line `viewModelScope.launch`, can anyone tell me which branch is missing?

```
fun demoDelete(pos : Int, deleted : Boolean) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val list = viewModel.currentState.listItem.toMutableList()
        list.mapIndexed { index, item -> 
            if (pos == index) {
                if (deleted == true) {
                    item.copy(update = UpdateType.DELETE)
                } else {
                    item.copy(update = UpdateType.ADD)
                }
            } else {
                item
            }
        }
        dispatchState(state = currentstate.copy(listItem = list))
    }
}
```